# Can I submit a javascript generated sitemap to Google

Tags: javascript, sitemap

I have a javascript website that is data generated from an external api. I do not have access to the api form the server side(dues to security lockdown within organisation) so cannot generate it here. So how do I generate a sitemap each day (as the data changes daily) via Javascript.

Ken

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **SEO** which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read ["Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?"](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618) to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not) and where you might be able to get assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end you need to give a URL with XML to Google in order for the sitemap to be processed. How you generate the XML is up to you, but the JavaScript would have to run in a server-environment (i.e. Node.js).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for response. Looks like server-side only xml is possible.